# Help for buying shotgun microphone

Tags: microphone, shotgun, buy

Many of you might have been in a situation when you wanted to buy a microphone but didn’t find a comprehensive chart that helps you choose.
Well, I made one of shotgun mics.
More than 100 type.
I hope you’ll find it useful. I’ll try to update it time to time.

[Shotgun microphones comparison](http://debsound.com/?p=509)

**New Update 2015-04-28**

Comment: @Membrans Very nice list, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Great idea! I actually did something similar in excel when I was choosing gear.

Why don't we start something similar in google docs open to everyone? If more people get involved and can edit, we can have a more exhaustive table even with personal experiences about different gear.

In a few hours I'm going to open some excels to start with. I will post them here, you can join if you like!

Comment: I have just started a spreadsheet about recorders. The idea is not register every possible piece of gear but models that are interesting for some reason. The document is public so you can check it out or help if you want.


https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnnG0EFBglkwdFhjM2RHaVhqdEd4Rno1aE5fT2JXVlE

Answer (score 0):

Wow, great work, very comprehensive! Could you make it downloadable, or do you want to keep it online only?

Comment: I want to keep it online only, but i will update it. Perhaps i will make another sound gears table in the future (more mics, portable recorders, preamp etc.).

Answer (score 0):

data on sensitivity and self-noise, please.

Comment: I try to update :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, very informative and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Cool. It would be nice to have the AKG C568 and also mics from Beyerdynamic added to the list though